# Access to variables in surrounding context from within Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, scoping, variable-definitions

Suppose you want to access a variable defined in a "surrounding" context (scoped via `Begin` and `End`) from within `Manipulate`. The following naive attempt does not work.

```
Begin["MyContext`"];
x = 123;
Manipulate[x + y, {y, 0, 1}]
End[];
x = 456; (* changes the value of Manipulate output *)
```

One way to fix this is by using `Inactive` and `Activate` as follows.

```
Begin["MyContext`"];
x = 123;
Activate@Manipulate[Inactive[x] + y, {y, 0, 1}]
End[];
x = 456; (* does not change the value of Manipulate output *)
MyContext`x = 456; (* changes the value of Manipulate output *)
```

Is this a robust way to achieve the desired goal or do you see any problems using this pattern in more involved examples? If so which alternative solutions do you suggest?

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Does `Begin["MyContext\`"]; Manipulate[Module[{x = 123}, x + y], {y, 0, 1}]
End[]; x = 456;` do what you want?

Comment: I want to be able to refer to e.g. functions defined outside of `Manipulate` in a specific context like `MyContext:x`(colon -> backtick).

Comment: Markdown tip:  You can get a ``"`"`` in code by surrounding the code in double backticks ```"``"```: ```"``MyContext`x``"```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are showing can in principle work, under two conditions:

- You need to have the `Begin[…]` and `End[…]` parts in different cells. If you do not, the symbol `x` is already resolved to `` Global`x `` before the context is changed. This is because as a first step, the entire cell contents are converted into an expression using `MakeExpression`. Only then are the individual lines evaluated.
- `x` must not exist in the `` Global` ``  context when evaluating your code. This is because otherwise `x` is still resolved to `` Global`x ``, because `$ContextPath` still contains `` Global` `` , so no new symbol is created.¨

  ```
  Begin["MyContext`"];

  (* separate cell *)
  x = 123;

  Manipulate[x + y, {y, 0, 1}]

  (* separate cell *)
  End[];

  (* separate cell *)
  x = 456;(*does not change the value of Manipulate output*)
  ```

  [image]

Here are three approaches to make sure the second condition is not an issue:

- Use  `` `x `` instead of `x`. This makes sure you are referring to the `x` in the current context, and not `` Global`x ``

  ```
  x = 233;

  (* separate cell *)
  Begin["MyContext`"];

  `x = 123;

  Manipulate[`x + y, {y, 0, 1}]

  (* separate cell *)
  End[];

  (* separate cell *)
  x = 456;(*does not change the value of Manipulate output*)
  ```

  [image]
- Change `$ContextPath` temporarily.

  ```
  x = 233;

  Begin["MyContext`"];
  oldCP = $ContextPath; $ContextPath = {"System`", $Context};

  (* separate cell *)
  x = 123;

  Manipulate[x + y, {y, 0, 1}]

  (* separate cell *)
  $ContextPath = oldCP;
  End[];

  (* separate cell *)
  x = 456;(*does not change the value of Manipulate output*)
  ```

  [image]
- Use `BeginPackage` to handle `$ContextPath` for you.

  ```
  x = 233;

  (* separate cell *)
  BeginPackage["System`"];
  Begin["MyContext`"];

  (* separate cell *)
  x = 123;
  Manipulate[x + y, {y, 0, 1}]

  (* separate cell *)
  End[];
  EndPackage[];

  (* separate cell *)
  x = 456;(*does not change the value of Manipulate output*)
  ```

  [image]

  This makes use of the same strategy that is used for paclet development: You use `BeginPackage` to temporarily reset `$ContextPath` to a clean version, and use `Begin` to make a private context whose symbols are not seen from the outside. The only difference is that here, I'm using `` BeginPackage["System`"] `` in order not to create any superfluous contexts. You could also use `` BeginPackage["MyContext`"] ``, and then `` Begin["`Private`"] ``. You could then expose some of the symbols by declaring them before the `Begin[...]` part, and hide the other ones in the `` MyContext`Private` ``  subcontext.

To work around the issue mentioned by @MichaelE2 with the labels of the sliders, you can manually specify the label for the slider using the syntax `{{y,0,"y"},0,1}` to specify the slider.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and nice solutions. Of both approaches I like the backtick one (first approach) best because it is concise. However, it is easy to forget the backtick and thus introduce errors. The second approach seems slightly cumbersome. Can you think of another way? If no other solution comes up, I will accept your answer.

Comment: +1. The second method is somewhat "fragile": If you evaluate the `Manipulate` output, it displays ``MyContext`y`` next to the `Manipulator` instead of just `y`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for pointing that out! I have added a comment at the bottom for how to work around that by specifying the label explicitly.

Comment: @MathGaudium Please see the third approach for a "cleaner" version of the second one.

Comment: Very nice suggestions and discussion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of `` $CellContext` ``  and the cell option `CellContext`:

```
Remove@x;
Begin["MyContext`"];
x = 123;
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[
  Manipulate[x + y, {y, 0, 1}],
  "Output",
  CellContext -> Context[]
  ]
 ]
End[];
x = 456;   (* does not change the value of Manipulate output *)
MyContext`x = 789; (* changes the value of Manipulate output *)
```

*Caveat:*

If the output cell generated above is copied and pasted, all works fine.

If only the `Manipulate` in the output cell is copied and it is pasted into an existing cell, then the context of that cell will be used.  Normally the cell context is `` Global` `` .

**Alternate method**

In this alternative, `Manipulate` sets the cell context.  If the `Manipulate` output is copied and pasted into another cell, it will overwrite that cell's context to `` "MyContext`" ``.

```
Begin["MyContext`"];
`x = 123; (* Lukas Lang's suggestion *)
With[{context = Context[]},
 Manipulate[x + y, {y, 0, 1},
  Initialization :> (CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellContext] = 
     context
    )
  ]
 ]
End[];
```

Comment: Thank you. Your "alternate method" requires also `Remove@x` in the beginning. Otherwise `x` stays symbolic in the output of `Manipulate`. I wonder what would be an elegant way to deal with this without removing `x` from ``"Global`"``. Can you think of alternatives to the suggestion of Lukas Lang?

Comment: @MathGaudium Yeah, I had `Remove@x` in my code on my machine, but thought it would be clear if I just highlighted the changes. Not sure why I thought that now. The need for `Remove` comes down to how packages work. *New* variables are created in the current context; *old* ones keep their contexts. You can write ``MyContext`x = 123`` in the external code. Or you can change `CellContext` of the `Begin...End[]` input cell to ``"MyContext`"``.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation again. It would be really good if there would be a way to "open" a context and have variables be assigned in this context regardless of whether they exist in the Global context or not.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate is a Dynamics module and I do not think the `Context` you are setting affects it.

One can see this by doing `Print[Context[]];` from inside Manipulate. The context you are setting do not extend to it:

```
Begin["MyContext`"];
Print[Context[]]; (*this prints MyContext`*)
Manipulate[
 Print[Context[]]; (*this prints Global`*)
 x = 100;
 Print["the above x sits in context ", Context[x]]; (*this prints Global`*)
 y,
 {{y, 0, "y"}, 0, 1, .1}
 ]
End[];
```

[image]

But if you want to modify the `x` used Manipulate from outside, Why not just leave it global?

```
ClearAll[x, y];
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{"x", x}, {"x+y", x + y}}, Frame -> All],
 {{y, 0, "y"}, 0, 1, .1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}
 ]
```

And now from outside Manipulate you can do `x = 99;` and Manipulate will update.

[image]

btw, I would not do any of these things myself. You are just asking for trouble.

Better to have all the variables to be controlled inside Manipulate and not make it use Global variables to update, and use a `Module` inside Manipulate to protect non-controlled variable from outside.    That is the standard way to use Manipulate. You can also use its Initialization section to initialize things if needed.

Comment: If you put ``"Begin["MyContext`"];"`` in a separate cell, `Print[Context[]]` inside `Manipulate` actually does print ``"MyContext`"``.